# How to fetch XLS data in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, email, addressbook, xls

I want to make an iPhone application which fetches XLS data from mail attachments and adds it into the iPhone AddressBook. I am new to the iPhone SDK. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the contents of an Excel document with the `UIWebView` class. But there is no built-in functionality to parse an Excel document, to extract data from it. Consider using CSV or other text-based, non-proprietary formats, if you can.